# I want HTML seekbar with 5 values, when value show image1, also like value 2 show image2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using JavaScript or jQuery, how can I display an image of a selected class (and hide all other images of that class) by changing the value of a seekbar (input range slider) ?

When value1 is selected, image1 should be shown, and all other images hidden, etc.

Comment: Slow down ;) First, welcome to StackOverflow. Second, please read "how to ask" article, so we can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. **Try this [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/siberi/edit?html,js,output) for a demo.**

When the value of the input slider element changes, we use that value as an index for the images with the class-name "image". Then we hide all of those images, and show the image that corresponds with the selected index.

You can use either vanilla Javascript (no jQuery) **or** jQuery.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var slider = document.getElementById('image-slider');

slider.addEventListener('change', function(){
  var images = document.getElementsByClassName('image');
  var index = this.value;

  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i ++) {
    images[i].style.display = 'none';
  }

  images[index].style.display = 'block';

}, false)
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#image-slider').on('input', function(){
  var index = this.value;

  // hide all the images first
  $('.image').hide();

  // show selected image
  $('.image').eq(index).show();

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <input id="image-slider" type="range" min="0" max="4" step="1" value="1">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.funnycatpix.com/_pics/Whaaa_Hahaha244_t.jpg" alt="" hidden>
  <img class="image" src="http://www.funnycatpix.com/_pics/This_Pizza_Box_Is_Great_t.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.funnycatpix.com/_pics/Kitten_Cuddlers_t.jpg" alt="" hidden>
  <img class="image" src="http://www.funnycatpix.com/_pics/First_Time_In_The_Grass_t.jpg" alt="" hidden>
  <img class="image" src="http://www.funnycatpix.com/_pics/Play_With_Me_Instead435_t.jpg" alt="" hidden>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Tom Yates, can i have a another doubt, can you change the values to percentage because i want smooth scrool, once again thankyou soo much tom

Comment: Check **[this JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/kenoxe/edit?html,js,output)**. If you feel this answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. Thanks,

Comment: This is successfully solved my problem thanks a lot Tom Yates, I want another question plz help me, when i am seekbar moving how to add HTML class to add css animations, Transitions Thanks,

Comment: It depends. If you want to do a simple fadeIn() then you can do something [like this](http://jsbin.com/kenoxe/edit?html,js,output) (updated). If you want something else, ask a new question and I'll be happy to answer :-)

Comment: Thank you so much tom, its ok but i want css3 animations like @-webkit-keyframe animation cubic-bezier animations to improve UI Please help me once again thankyou som much tom yates

Comment: Like I said, I'd be happy to answer this if you post a new question. "If you ask several questions in one question you risk having answers that are both correct and wrong at the same time." Otherwise look at this http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/